# Proving that $\int_{M}1d\sigma$ is equal $\int_{U}\sqrt{1+\left\Vert \nabla f\right\Vert ^{2}}du_{1}\ldots du_{n-1}$ when M is a graph of f

Tags: analysis, differential-geometry, manifolds

I am trying to prove that if M is a manifold of n-1 dimension, that can be described as a graph of function $f:U\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ than it's surface area is $\int_{U}\sqrt{1+\left\Vert \nabla f\right\Vert ^{2}}du_{1}\ldots du_{n-1}$.

So first of all, I know that if we have $$r\left(x_{1},\ldots,x_{n-1}\right)=\left(x_{1},x_{2},\ldots,x_{n-1},f\left(x_{1},\ldots,x_{n-1}\right)\right)$$ and $$G=\begin{pmatrix}\left\Vert \partial_{1}r\right\Vert ^{2} & \left\langle \partial_{1}r,\partial_{2}r\right\rangle  & \ldots & \left\langle \partial_{1}r,\partial_{n-1}r\right\rangle \\
\left\langle \partial_{1}r,\partial_{2}r\right\rangle  & \left\Vert \partial_{2}r\right\Vert ^{2}\\
\vdots &  & \ddots\\
\left\langle \partial_{1}r,\partial_{n-1}r\right\rangle  &  &  & \left\Vert \partial_{n-1}r\right\Vert ^{2}
\end{pmatrix}$$ we have $\intop_{M}1d\sigma=\intop_{U}\sqrt{\text{det}G}$ so basically i want to prove $\text{det}G=1+\left\Vert \nabla f\right\Vert ^{2}$ I also realized that $$G_{i,j}=\begin{cases}
\partial_{i}f\partial_{j}f & i\neq j\\
1+\left(\partial_{i}f\right)^{2} & i=j
\end{cases}$$ so I tried looking at G-I and proving that it has eigenvalues $\partial_{1}f,\ldots,\partial_{n-1}f$ But i am stuck here, I got that for every vector u i get: $$\left(G-I\right)\left(v\right)=\begin{pmatrix}\partial_{1}f\left(\partial_{1}fv_{1}+\ldots+\partial_{n-1}fv_{n-1}\right)\\
\partial_{2}f\left(\partial_{1}fv_{1}+\ldots+\partial_{n-1}fv_{n-1}\right)\\
\vdots\\
\partial_{n-1}f\left(\partial_{1}fv_{1}+\ldots+\partial_{n-1}fv_{n-1}\right)
\end{pmatrix}$$ but i didn't manage to find any eigenvalues.

Any help is welcomed, thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are very close to the answer. From your computations, you have shown that $$G=I_{n-1} +\nabla f \otimes \nabla f $$ where $I_{n-1}$ is the $(n-1)$-identity matrix, $\nabla$ is the gradient in $\mathbb R^{n-1}$, and $u\otimes v$ is the [outer product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_product) of $u$ and $v$. Then it follows from the [matrix determinant lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_determinant_lemma) that $$ \det G = 1 + \nabla f \cdot \nabla f = 1 + \vert \nabla f \vert^2  $$ which completes the proof.

Comment: Ohhh I see, it does solve my problem, thanks you very much, I actually never knew about this lemma.

Do you maybe see another way to solve that problem? I am just curious as I wouldn't manage it without that lemma and want to know if I was capable of solving it another way.

Comment: @Abzikro Good question. I'm not certain that the approach you mention above will work. Even if $G-I$ does have eigenvalues $\partial_1f,\dots,\partial_{n-1}f$ (which I'm not convinced it does) you want to calculate $\det G$, so I don't see how this would help

Comment: At the end of the day you want to calculate $\det G$, so you could have done this like in Calculus 1 (or whenever you first learnt determinants of matrices) and used Laplace expansion or Gaussian elimination, but this could be messy. If you did try it this way, I'd recommend doing $n=2$ first then proceeding by induction on $n$

Comment: Thank you for your help!
In case you're intrested, finally, I managed to do it using the fact that trace(G-I) is the sum of it's eigenvalues.
So $$G-I=\begin{pmatrix}\partial_{1}f\left(\nabla f\right) & \partial_{2}f\left(\nabla f\right) & \ldots & \partial_{n-1}f\left(\nabla f\right)\end{pmatrix}$$ meaning it's diagonalizable and its karnel is of of dimension n-2, so all it's eigenvalues except at most one are 0, but $\text{trace}\left(G-I\right)=\left\Vert \nabla f\right\Vert ^{2}$ meaning the eigenvalues of G are 1 and $\left\Vert \nabla f\right\Vert ^{2}+1$ and we done